# vuejs condition to compare the if userConnect.id with the post.user_id changes display else you show me there is no post, what 's solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

here my template with all request

```js
<template>
  <div
    v-if="
      postes.filter((poste) => {
        return poste.post_id === userConnect.id;
      })
    "
    class=" d-flex flex-column my-5 align-items-center justify-content-center "
  >
    <div
      v-for="(poste, id) in filterPost.slice().reverse()"
      v-bind:key="id"
      class="largeur80 d-flex align-items-center my-5 justify-content-center card bordurePost bordureRond border-primary shadow"
    >
      <div class="card-body p-3 container-fluid">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <img
              v-if="
                users
                  .map((user) => {
                    if (user.id === poste.user_id) return user.image_url;
                  })
                  .join('') !== (null || '')
              "
              :src="
                users
                  .map((user) => {
                    if (user.id === poste.user_id) return user.image_url;
                  })
                  .join('')
              "
              width="100px"
              height="100px"
              class=" justify-content-left bordureProfil
          rounded-circle"
            />
            <img
              v-else
              src="../assets/image/icon.png"
              width="100px"
              class=" justify-content-left bordureProfil rounded-circle"
            />
            <div class="ml-3 align-item-center justify-content-center">
              <h5>
                {{
                  users
                    .map((user) => {
                      if (user.id === poste.user_id) return user.email;
                    })
                    .join("")
                }}
                {{
                  users
                    .map((user) => {
                      if (user.id === poste.user_id) return user.id;
                    })
                    .join("")
                }}
              </h5>
              <h6>Publié le: {{ poste.date_cree }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          <b-button
            v-if="userConnect.id == poste.user_id"
            @click="deletePost(poste)"
            size="sm"
            variant="danger"
            class="bg-light mb-2 minHeight30"
          >
            <b-icon
              icon="trash-fill"
              variant="danger"
              aria-label="false"
            ></b-icon>
          </b-button>
        </div>

        <h4 class=" largeur100 card-title">{{ poste.titre }}</h4>
        <div class=" my-3">
          <img
            v-if="poste.image_link !== '' && poste.image_link !== null"
            class="card-img-top"
            height="400px"
            :src="poste.image_link"
            alt="img-or-video"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="text-left  text-wrap py-3 card-text">
            {{ poste.description }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div
          v-for="(comment, id) in comments.filter((comment) => {
            return comment.post_id == poste.id;
          })"
          v-bind:key="id"
          class="d-flex mb-2 align-items-center justify-content-center align-content-center"
        >
          <img
            v-if="
              comment.user_id === userConnect.id &&
                (!userConnect.image_url == null || '')
            "
            :src="userConnect.image_url"
            width="60px"
            height="60px"
            class=" mr-3 justify-content-left bordurePost
          rounded-circle"
            alt=""
          />
          <img
            v-else
            src="../assets/image/icon.png"
            width="60px"
            height="60px"
            class=" mr-3 justify-content-left bordurePost
          rounded-circle"
            alt=""
          />

          <div
            class=" d-inline-flex flex-column align-items-start pl-3 largeur100 minHeight bordureRond bodurePost border border-primary backPrimaire"
            min-heigth="60px"
          >
            <p class="stopOpac stopPadMarg text-dark">
              {{
                users.map((user) => {
                  if (user.id === comment.user_id) return user.prenom;
                })
              }}
              {{ userConnect.nom }}
            </p>
            <p class="stopOpac text-left stopPadMarg text-secondary">
              {{ comment.comment }}
            </p>
          </div>
          <b-button
            size="sm"
            variant="danger"
            class="d-flex justify-content-center bg-light ml-2 minHeight25 minwidth25"
          >
            <b-icon
              icon="trash-fill"
              variant="danger"
              aria-label="false"
            ></b-icon>
          </b-button>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-1 form-group">
          <label class="text-primary" for="commentaire"
            >Laisser un commentaire</label
          >
          <div
            class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center align-content-center"
          >
            <img
              v-if="
                poste.user_id === userConnect.id &&
                  (userConnect.image_url !== null || '')
              "
              :src="userConnect.image_url"
              width="50px"
              height="50px"
              class=" mr-3 justify-content-left bordurePost
          rounded-circle"
              alt=""
            />
            <img
              v-else
              src="../assets/image/icon.png"
              width="50px"
              height="50px"
              class=" mr-3 justify-content-left bordurePost
          rounded-circle"
              alt=""
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              name="commentaire"
              placeholder="Commentaires..."
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else><h1>Il n'y a aucun postes actuellement !!!</h1></div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "carte",
  data() {
    return {
      postes: [],
      users: [],
      userDef: [],
      userConnect: [],
      comments: [],
      user_id: localStorage.getItem("userId"),
      userChoice: localStorage.getItem("userChoice"),
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filterUser() {
      return this.users.filter((user) => {
        return user.id;
      });
    },
    filterUserimage() {
      return this.users.filter((user) => {
        return user.image_url;
      });
    },
    filterUsernom() {
      return this.users.filter((user) => {
        return user.nom;
      });
    },
    filterPost() {
      return this.postes.filter((poste) => {
        return poste.user_id == this.userConnect.id;
      });
    },
    filterComm() {
      return this.comments.filter((comment) => {
        return comment.user_id == this.userConnect.id;
      });
    },
  },

  async created() {
    this.postes = [];
    this.users = [];
    this.userDef = [];
    this.userConnect = [];
    //this.postes = [];
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/postes")
      .then(
        (response) => ((this.postes = response.data), console.log(response))
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .then(
        (response) => ((this.users = response.data), console.log(this.users))
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .then(
        (response) => (
          (this.userDef = response.data.find((user) => {
            return user.id;
          })),
          console.log(this.userDef)
        )
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/user/${this.userChoice}`)
      .then(
        (response) => (
          (this.userConnect = response.data), console.log(this.userConnect.id)
        )
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/commentaires")
      .then(
        (response) => (
          (this.comments = response.data), console.log(this.comments)
        )
      )
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  },

  methods: {
    deletePost(poste) {
      axios
        .delete(`http://localhost:3000/poste/${poste.id}`, {})
        .then((response) => {
          //(this.submitStatus = "OK"),
          console.log(response), this.$router.go("/post");
        })
        .catch((error) =>
          // (this.submitStatus = "ERROR SERVEUR"),
          console.log(error)
        );
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

i made a condition at the top of the div but it doesn't work the else condition is at the end what is the correct solution here ??

[image]

the carteChoice template must be displayed below the last posts but nothing is displayed does not change with this condition and the sentence there are no posts currently if there are no posts userConnect.id === post.user_id else them posts should appear.

[image]

here user connect and postes vue dev tools

[image]

Comment: Try to place `postes.filter((poste) => {
        return poste.post_id === userConnect.id;
      })` in some computed prop and look if it's empty or not after loading (in Vue dev tools)

Comment: I already have this filter in the computed but how to check with the condition if else please ?? here look                     filterPost() {
      return this.postes.filter((poste) => {
        return poste.user_id == this.userConnect.id;
      });
    },

Comment: here on the top vue dev tools but what's condition into if else please??

Comment: Can you show a content of `postes` and `userConnect` in vue dev tools? Just expand them and replace a screenshoot

Comment: here i just add on the top

Comment: At least `userConnect` should be initialized as an array. Instead it should be like `{ id: null }`

Comment: There's many problems with your code, try changing `v-if="postes.filter((poste) => {return poste.post_id === userConnect.id;})"` to `v-if="postes && postes.some(poste => poste.post_id == userConnect.id)"`

Comment: the correct response below not poste.post_id but poste.user_id == userConnect.id thanks you but the syntax is great and works

Answer (score 1):

here the condition great thanks fryour response All developper send me my problem

```
  <div
v-if="postes && postes.some((poste) => poste.user_id == userConnect.id)"
class=" d-flex flex-column my-5 align-items-center justify-content-center "><div>
```

and the end of the template

```
<div v-else>
<h1>il n' y a pas de poste actuellement</h1></div>
```